# xna 4.0 visual studio 2010 error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, compiler-errors, xna-4.0, xna-3.0

when i try and compile a solution i recieve the following error

> error x3539 ps_1_x is no longer supported
>
> (68,23); ID3DXEffectCompiler;;CompileEffect: There was an error compiling expression ID3DXEffectCompiler: compilation failed

I believe this is an issue to do with the version of XNA and visial studios i am using because the code was created on visual studio 2008 and used XNA 3.0, but now i have xna 4.0 and visual studios 2010.

could anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch your shader from `ps_1_1` to `ps_2_0`.  Since you haven't provided any source...  [see the XNA 3.1 to XNA 4.0 cheat sheet for more information.](http://nelxon.com/resources/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet.php)  Good luck!